# using hook_query_alter with fieldcondition()

Tags: hooks, database

I want to use hook_query_alter to alter a query constructed by a module. This is the code I use:

```
function MYMODULE_query_alter($query) {
  if ($query->hasTag('agent')) {
    $query->fieldCondition('field_area', 'tid', 10, '=');
  }
}
```

The code above gives a 500 error: Call to undefined method SelectQuery::fieldCondition()

What is the proper way to add a field condition to the query?

Comment: `fieldCondition()` is a method from the [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class, it's not part of a standard database query.

Comment: yes, it took me some time to realize this. However, the question remains.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved using the [$query->innerJoin()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQueryInterface%3a%3ainnerJoin/7)

Answer (score 0):

To use condition in query simply use:

```
$query->condition('field_area', 'tid', 10, '=');
```